# Selenium Unable to find text in webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, text, find

I want to locate the first result in the search of this page https://www.se.com/ww/en/search/rxm4ab2bd

with
:"RXM4AB2BD | Product"

```html
<div dir="auto" class="result-card"><a class="link-area" href="https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/RXM4AB2BD"><uiaas-search-result-product imagecontain="" class="hydrated"><uiaas-search-result-basic imagecontain="" class="hydrated"><!----><div class=""><uiaas-search-result-card-generic-template class="hydrated"><div slot="search-result-ribbon"></div><uiaas-search-result-public-header-template slot="search-result-header" class="hydrated"><div class="result"><uiaas-search-result-title class="hydrated"><div><a class="result-title__link" href="https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/RXM4AB2BD" target="_self"><h3 class="result-title"><span>Miniature plug in relay, Harmony, 6A, 4CO, with LED, lockable test button, 24V DC</span></h3></a></div></uiaas-search-result-title><div class="result-details result-header__details"><div class="result-details-item result-details-sku"><span class="result-type"><span class="highlight">RXM4AB2BD</span></span><span class="result-details-item__vertical-bar">|</span></div><div class="result-details-item"><span class="result-type">Product</span><span class="result-details-item__vertical-bar">|</span></div></div></div></uiaas-search-result-public-header-template><div slot="search-result-content"><span class="result-description">Miniature plug in relay, Harmony, 6A, 4CO, with LED, lockable test button, 24V DC</span><div slot="search-result-additional-content" class="search-result-additional-content"></div></div></uiaas-search-result-card-generic-template><div slot="result-eshop" class="result-eshop"></div></div></uiaas-search-result-basic></uiaas-search-result-product></a></div>
```

No matter what I try I can't get even find RXM4AB2BD.

I tried:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'RXM4AB2BD')]")))
```

I checked and there are no frame in the page

Answer (score -3):

In order for 'contains()' to work you need to provide a partial string.. Here you have provided exact string. Provide a partial String like "RXM4" and try.

try using below code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'RXM4')]")))
```

Comment: No, same.
Partial entree doesn't help.
I think I tried all possible Xpath already.
I suspect that the structure of the page makes it such that something must be done before the find can work (I thought of changing frame but there are none)

Comment: my html knowledge is very succinct. 
Maybe try looking at the page to see if something needs to be done before the find_element(By.XPATH